# Custom notification system database improve efficiency when sending to all users

Tags: database-design, architecture

I am creating custom notifications system for my web app. Basically these notifications are system messages to users, because the sender is always the system.

Here is the structure I am thinking of:

```
notifications
-id
-message

users_notifications
-id
-user_id
-notification_id
-read
-created_at
-read_at
```

Now then the problem I am having is that, my web app has companies and users tables, users belongs to companies.

Some messages will be sent to companies a.k.a. all users in companies. 
Also some messages will be sent to all users of the system.

Now then I think it is inefficient to make n (for all users or all company users) entries in `users_notifications` table, so my question is how should I handle this to improve efficiency?

Should I create `companies_notifications` table for company notifications, but then what should I do with all users?

Comment: Do you want to keep only new notifications or history of notification in companies_notifications table?

Comment: I think that I want to store the history of notifications.

Comment: Does a user have only one company? Can a user change company?

Comment: Yes user has only one company and he wont change it. @MaximFedorov